# Generating unique random number in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I want to generate random number from 1 to 9 and i want them to be unique. This is the code i have written which gives me 9 different numbers from 1 to 9 but I have no clue on generating unique number.

```
 int data[] = new int[10];
      for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();

            data[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
          System.out.println(data[i]);

        }
```

Comment: Look at "Related" list on right hand side. How do you explain that?

Comment: Have a look at my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233896/java-securerandom-nextint-vs-nextgaussian which may be useful

Comment: I would suggest to use different solution : 1) Store 1 to 9 numbers in an array 2) Use Math.random(10) to get one of these 10 numbers from array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill a `List<Integer> list` with 1..9 and then:

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Note that to fill an array of 10, you'll have to have one duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store  1 to 9 numbers in an Array.
2. Generate random number between 1 to 9 as position and return array[position-1] to get the value
3. Once you use a number in array, mark the value as -1.
4. If value in array is -1, get the random number again

Comment: And how do you guarantee to avoid getting the same number twice? How is this any different from generating random numbers in the range 1..9 (0..8)?

Comment: whenever you get a number, use it and make the value in that location as -1. Have a loop to draw random number again if value of array element is -1